# Update Column A where Column B has Value C in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Good morning,

I'm trying to update a DataFrame based on the contents of two columns and am running into issues.

Specifically, I have a column called `IP`, another called `VISITTIME`. I've added two columns called `OLDEST` and `NEWEST` which need to contain the min and max `VISITTIME` for the `IP` of that row.

Using:

```
df2 = pd.merge(df.groupby('IP')['VISITTIME'].min().to_frame(), 
               df.groupby('IP')['VISITTIME'].max().to_frame(), on="IP")
```

I can get the min and max times for each `IP` in the table. I can then iterate over that but I don't know how to update the original `DataFrame`.

Essentially what I'm asking is how do I do the following in `pandas`:

```
UPDATE df SET df.OLDEST = df2.OLDEST, df.NEWEST = df2.NEWEST WHERE df.IP=df2.IP;
```

I feel like this should be easy and I'm ashamed that it isn't.

Thank you

Comment: Please add an example of input data and expected output.

Comment: See: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/3339965)

Comment: look at `pd.update()`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your version of pandas (I know in version > 0.22.0), 
there is a method called [Dataframe.update](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.update.html).

That should provide some examples, but a few warnings:

- You need to make sure that both dataframes are using IP as an index,
  or this method will not work.
- The column (Series) names should be the same, so it will not require any location or column referencing.
- You may choose to only overwrite NA values, but not applicable for what you are describing here.

---

```
DataFrame.update(other, join='left', overwrite=True, filter_func=None, raise_conflict=False)
```

Modify in place using non-NA values from another DataFrame.

Aligns on indices. There is no return value.